# File Upload or Image Upload In angular 6 with spring boot

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, file-upload, multipartform-data

**Please help me or suggest me**

**---------------#################---------------**

***What is a possible way to upload an image in a form using formcontrolName if possible please give some suggestion***

**------------###########################---------------------**

I am trying to upload an image file with other information like `firstname`, `lastname` and `file` and this is working perfect:

```
/* File Upload request  to Upload file  */
this.currentFileUpload = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
let formdata: FormData = new FormData();
formdata.append('firstName', "Harkesh");
formdata.append('lastName', "kumar");
formdata.append('file', this.currentFileUpload);
```

But my problem is I am sending `FORM` file with some string and `Object`, but  `FormData` doesn't accept `Object`:

```
let formdata: FormData = new FormData();
formdata.append('functionId', this.functionId);
formdata.append('processId', this.processId);
formdata.append('file', this.currentFileUpload);
formdata.append('formDetails', userobjArr);
```

2nd option I am trying:

```
let formdata: FormData = new FormData();
formdata.append('file', this.currentFileUpload);

userDetails.name = "";
userobjWrapper["functionId"] = this.functionId;
userobjWrapper["processId"] = this.processId;
userobjWrapper["taskId"] = this.taskId;
userobjWrapper["file"] = this.currentFileUpload;
userobjWrapper["formDetails"] = userobjArr;
```

`userobjArr` is `Object` array that I assign with `formDetails` this is getting `null` value.

I am not sure how to do read image in one rest Service API calls? and for rest API I am using spring boot Rest Controller

can you suggest me any idea..

Comment: if you not able to answer please share or edit upvote so I  and you can get  answer

Comment: Did you print userobjArr in console
if it is a form Object then userobjArr.getRawData()

Comment: yes i can print

Comment: Perhaps I'm oversimplifying or misunderstand the issue, but can you not just JSON encode the object into a string and JSON decode it on the other side?

Comment: i am not way you are saying

Comment: Encode it with JSON.stringify(userobjArr). Decode it to get the original format back.

Comment: you saying decode its java side

Answer (score 1):

try this one :)

```
onBmpFileUploadChange(event) {
    const self = this;
    const target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    const files = target.files;
    let arrPath = files[0].name;
    arrPath = arrPath.split('.');
    if ((arrPath[1] === 'bmp') || (arrPath[1] === 'BMP')) {
      const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      const formData = new FormData();
      console.log('uploadBitmap');
      formData.append('bitmapFile', files[0]);
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        event.target.value = null;
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
          if (this.status === 201) {
            console.log('bmpUploadedSuccessfully');
          } else {
            console.log('bmpUploadFailed')));
          }
        }
      };
      xhttp.open('post', '/formatgraphics', true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache');
      xhttp.send(formData);
    } else {
      console.log('uploadFailedInvalidFile')));
    }
  }
}
```